# is there a way to improve this query by not re calculating functions? cross apply?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication, scripting, cross-apply

when I set up replication I like to take a count of each table in the publisher, then I go to the subscriber I do the same thing in order to compare both pictures.

this is the picture from the publisher:

[image]

in order to generate this picture I run the following query:

```
USE ORCASTG_CA18_Repl
go
SELECT 
         Publication=P.name 
        --,Publication_description=p.description
        ,p.immediate_sync
        ,p.allow_anonymous
        ,p.replicate_ddl
        ,the_schema=OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(a.objid)
        ,TableName = a.name
        ,DestinationServer=s.srvname
        ,DestinationDB=s.dest_db
        ,DestinationSchema= a.dest_owner
        ,DestinationTable = A.dest_table  
        ,Radhe='exec sp_count ' +'''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(a.objid)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(a.name) + ''''

FROM dbo.syspublications P 

INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles A 
        ON P.pubid = A.pubid

INNER JOIN dbo.syssubscriptions s 
        ON a.artid = s.artid 

WHERE 1=1
  AND s.dest_db <> 'virtual'
```

and that produces the following script:

```
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_application_placement]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationCalendarRequest]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationChecklist]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationFlightDetail]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationFlightLegDetail]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationFlightReference]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationProfile]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationRequestFlightOption]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationSkill]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_ApplicationVisaDetail]'
exec sp_count '[dbo].[repl_camp_profile]'
```

My question is:

Is there a way I can calculate the following line without re-running those functions:

```
,Radhe='exec sp_count ' +'''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(a.objid)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(a.name) + ''''
```

I thought about `cross apply`!

Comment: I am trying to avoid calculating `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(a.objid)` twice for each row. Let alone if there is any benefit in doing it, is it something possible?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you want to store the results of the multiple procs in a single run.
If that's the case then

I am not sure about what are the columns returned by the procedure `sp_count`
I am assuming that it returns `tablename,total_count`

So your code will be like this

```
USE ORCASTG_CA18_Repl
go
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #table_count (table_name varchar(128), table_count INT)

  SELECT  @sql=COALESCE(@sql+ '', '') 
           + 'INSERT INTO #table exec sp_count ' 
           +'''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(a.objid)) 
           + '.' + QUOTENAME(a.name) +';'+'''')

FROM dbo.syspublications P 

INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles A 
        ON P.pubid = A.pubid

INNER JOIN dbo.syssubscriptions s 
        ON a.artid = s.artid 

WHERE 1=1
  AND s.dest_db <> 'virtual'

  EXEC (@sql)

  SELECT * FROM #table_count tc
```

Also note, I have not tested the code. If you find issues when running please feel free to edit it.

**Edit 1:**
You can also use  the below methods instead of `COALESCE()`

`STRING_AGG()` (2017 onwards)

`XML string concatenation`

`GROUP_CONCAT` CLR method ([Github](https://github.com/orlando-colamatteo/ms-sql-server-group-concat-sqlclr))

All these is mentioned in the [Aaron bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)'s blog [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation)